# How to move "Solution Explorer" tab in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2005, development-environment, tabs

Does anyone know how to move the "Solution Explorer" tab in Visual Studio 2005?  It's on the left, and I can't move it to the right.

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Click on the title bar, and drag it to the right portion of the screen.  Eventually you'll see a compas like structure popup.  Make sure you hover over the right area and let go of the mouse button.  That will bind it to the right side.

Comment: Thanks!  (I had it in full-screen mode, where this didn't work.)

Answer (score 36):

You Can go to tab Windows -> Reset Windows Layout. Other options like Dockable, Floating and Tabbed Document are also their.

Answer (score 6):

you move the whole solution explorer while its floating on the screen. Right click--> Tabbed Document.
right click again --> Vertical tab

Comment: I had to also enable Auto Hide.

Answer (score 6):

To complement what the accepted answer gives, if you want it to look like this (on the left side):

[image: Left most sidebar]

Do the exact same procedure, and then after it has attached to the left side, click on "Auto Hide":

[image: Toolbar menu]

This way, it will stay visible on the toolbar.

Comment: Or you can only click the pin-icon, then it will also do the action "Auto Hide", and you will see a entry in the toolbar from this window, where you click the pin-icon

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for anyone looking to change tab placement in Visual Studio 2019, right click the open tab, select [Set Tab Layout] then a position: Left, Top, Right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only drag the panel by the title bar to the central compass overlay while it is pinned and not set to auto hide. You can click the pin icon in the title bar to toggle this.

Answer (score -1):

Go to View-> Appearance -> Move Side Bar Left